# superlative or comparison

Tags: adjectives, comparatives, superlative-degree

I have a question about some sentences.

> John is better than Sarah and Mary.

or

> John is the best.

If I'm comparing three things (John, Sarah, Mary), why am I using a comparative adjective?

I thought it was only for two people or things, but this is three.

Comment: Both are grammatical English sentences, and they can both describe the same phenomena. Why you are using one instead of the other, however, is something only you can tell.

Comment: I think you have in mind what used to be regarded as either an imprecise or even incorrect use.  A: “Who will get there first, John or Mary?”.  B:  Oh John, of course:  he is by far the fad the fastest.”. This used to be regarded as faulty because ONLY two things are being compared.  So B should say “...he is ... the faster.”. So the idea was that when you are comparing two things. you should use the comparative and not the superlative..  But that rule went by the board quite some time ago.    What would sound odd would be “John is the faster of the three”.

Comment: You're not using 'John is better than Sarah and Mary' to mean 'John is better than {Sarah and Mary [together]} but 'John is better than Sarah; he is also better than Mary'. You're comparing pairwise (and using a deletion to save words), so 'better' is correct. This persists in say 'Messi is better than all the rest', though I wouldn't give him much chance of winning when taking on 11 good players on his own.

Comment: @Tuffy, So do you mean when comparing two things the comparative and the superlative are both perfectly acceptable (in what contexts?)?

Comment: @HeWhoMustBeNamed I wouldn’t say ‘acceptable’:  ‘accepted’ is the word I use.  Other things being equal, English speakers tend to shed distinctions that make no difference to their being understood.  There are certain ‘brakes’ on this process:  school (and university) teachers, school English text books, grammar books, and editors of books, journals and newspapers.  There is also social snobbery:  that is, certain ‘mistakes’ (like this one) give us an excuse to look down on the speaker/writer as ‘uneducated’ and so of lower status.  But those brakes have weakened for obvious reasons.

Comment: @Tuffy Okay, thanks. A tangential point, though: by 'I wouldn’t say ‘acceptable’: "accepted' is the word I use,' do you mean that, while *accepted* by many speakers, this use of the superlative hasn't yet reached the status of being *acceptable*, or do you mean you don't like the word "acceptable" as it invokes some privileged class of people who get to *accept* and *non-accept* things?

Comment: @HeWhoMustBeNamed Neither, I’m afraid.  I am a descriptivist, and usage, as I understand it, relates to practice rather than obligation.  Personally, I regret the ‘smoothing out’ of précise distinctions from the language, because with it care over choice of expression is smoothed away.  But It is a fact, nonetheless.

Comment: @Tuffy Sorry but I still don't understand from your last comment what you had meant. I may have been unclear in my previous comment: by "do you mean that, while *accepted* by many speakers, this use of the superlative hasn't yet reached the status of being *acceptable*", I meant, do you mean that while that use of the superlative is accepted by some speakers, it is not widespread enough yet to be regarded *acceptable*. So when you said you prefer "accepted" over "acceptable" did you mean this, or something else -- maybe you were only expressing your like of the word "accepted" in general, ...

Comment: ...  not for some reason related to the matter of our discussion?

Comment: If the other two constitute a team, or a pair together against John, this sentence is correct.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, I think it's best to think of it as John Vs (Sarah and Mary).

The set is undefined, so it's unclear whether the superlative would be factually correct. If you were to prefix that with "In this class of three..", then the superlative works.